# Mask String of using regualr expressiond in java

Tags: java, regex

I need a code to mask the String using regular expressions.
need to mask digits with length is greater than or equal to 4.

```
public class Mask{
String data="+918033667777,,,2,,,4937015106932345,,,1,3,,,,467298364729038,,24789438292,,7979,,,,,,,1,,1";
    public static void main(String[] args){
       data = data.replaceAll("(?<=\\D)\\d{4}(?=\\D)", "****").replaceAll("\\d{12}(?=\\d{4})", "************");
       System.out.println(data);
    }
}
```

output: +918033667777,,,2,,,***************,,,1,3,,,,***************,,***********,,****,,,,,,,1,,1"
i,e i need to mask digits whose length is greater than or equal to 4.

Comment: Are `data` and `dialSequence` the same thing?

Comment: @NicholasRobinson yes they are same

Comment: But `+918033667777` is also a number with length more than 4. I get `+************,,,2,,,****************,,,1,3,,,,***************,,***********,,****,,,,,,,1,,1` with [my code sample](http://ideone.com/6yS9zu). Please check your  requirements.

Comment: @WashingtonGuedes that will not mask each character with `*` but each number with fixed amount of `*`.

Comment: @NicholasRobinson Even am getting the same output. i dont want to mask first set of digits. Need to mask only after ,(comma). how to skip these numbers(+918033667777)

Comment: @Pshemo yes , i need to replace with exact number of digits with *

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try with:

```
(?<=,)\d(?=\d{3,})|(?!\A)\G\d
```

[DEMO](https://regex101.com/r/bI1jQ1/2)

- `(?<=,)` - Positive lookbehind for comma
- `\d(?=\d{3,})` - Digit followed by three another digits (positive
  lookahead)
- `(?!\A)\G\d` - Check that the match continue from where previous match left off, followed by digit, the `(?!\A)` is for not matching first number in String. However, if you don't want to match only numbers preceded by `+`, it is redundant

Example in Java:

```
public class Test{

    public static void main(String[] args){
        String data="+918033667777,,,2,,,4937015106932345,,,1,3,,,,467298364729038,,24789438292,,7979,,,,,,,1,,1";
        data = data.replaceAll("(?<=,)\\d(?=\\d{3,})|(?!\\A)\\G\\d", "*");
        System.out.println(data);
    }
}
```

with output:

> +918033667777,,,2,,,****************,,,1,3,,,,***************,,***********,,****,,,,,,,1,,1

Comment: Little simplified Java version: `replaceAll("(?<!\\d)\\d(?=\\d{3})|\\G\\d", "*")`

Comment: @Pshemo but it will match also first number, as `\D` match also `+`

Comment: @Pshemo I dont want to mask first set of digits(+918033667777).Need to mask digits only after comma(,)

Comment: @Archana There is nothing about `,` in "mask digits with length is greater than or equal to 4." (or did I missed it?).

Comment: @stribizhev I added (?!\A) as it would match first number if not `+`, I assumed OP don't want to match first number

Comment: @Pshemo I wanted to mask digits which comes after , based on length which is greater than or equal to 4

Comment: @Archana is my regex work for you? Or output is not as expected?

Comment: @Archana Then please update your question and make it clear there (not many people willing to answer questions are reading comments under other answers first).

Comment: @m.cekiera Can you please tell me why \\G is used here

Comment: @Archana the \G match from a ending position of previous match, so if first alternative `(?<=,)\\d(?=\\d{3,})` match first digit after comma (if there is more digits following) then `\G\d` will match next digit, and every next, as previous was matched, so it kind of "chain reaction"

Comment: @stribizhev yes, even this (?<=,)\d(?=\d{3,})|\G\d is working.

Comment: @stribizhev yes, you are right, it is working, as I wrote in my answer if first number is preceded with `+` it is redundant